# Need ideas for automating on-chip testing on Cortex-M4 using gdb and semihosting

Tags: gdb, cortex-m, openocd

I'm working on safety-critical software that requires extensive testing. The target processor, a Cortex-M4, has rich resources for the application but the unit and integration tests, if aggregated, would be much larger than the on-board FLASH/RAM. They are designed to be run from gdb while using semi-hosting to off-load the test results. What's needed is a way to automate the testing so it can be run without per-test human intervention.

The test programs run fine from Eclipse using both OpenOCD and Segger debugger front-ends. These require per-test configurations and then manual starting of the tests. There will be 30-50 test programs so this isn't really viable for continuous integration or simple batch runs.

I've been looking around for possible ways to do this. There are a few tricky bits to consider. The first is supporting the semihosting of the output. That uses the breakpoint system to have the I/O from the host. In this use, a couple of files get opened on the host computer for logs. Another issue is ending the program being tested and loading the next. The programs can take a long time to run and drop into an infinite loop when the main() is exited. And the development platform is Windows 10.
The two basic ideas I've had are to use the gdb client library from cygwin to create a custom program or to use OpenOCD. Running through multiple tests could be done inside the application or from a Makefile. 
 Question: is the semihosting done in the gdb client or server?
So... Looking for some suggestions or experiences in creating what I picture as a custom gdb client in Win10.

Comment: The mbed greentea test automation tools might be relevant, although not aligned with what you're proposing at the moment. https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-tools/tree/master/packages/mbed-greentea